# Developing a Walkthrough Screen on Swift3

Tags: ios, swift

I am quite new in Swift and I am trying to develop a walkthrough screen for my application. I am following a book tutorial, but I get the following error and I can't continue.

I think the problem is in the different update of Swift. Would you please help me how to fix it?

```
self.pageViewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! UIPageViewController!) as! UIPageViewControllerDataSource!

let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) as ContentViewController
let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,30,self.view.frame.width,self.view.frame.height-60)

self.addChildViewController(pageViewController as! UIViewController)
self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your complete error.

Comment: You didn't post any error.

Comment: I uploaded a picture

Comment: And the picture doesn't show any error messages.

Comment: CGRectMake and self.pageViewController.datasource = self are in red

Comment: Again, your picture doesn't show any error messages. Yes, we can see which lines have an error but you need to post the actual error messages so people know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pageViewController` type is `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`. It is a protocol, not `UIViewController`.
You do not need to cast `UIPageViewController` to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`. You need to implement a `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and set `pageViewController` data source.

```
var pageViewController: UIPageViewController

self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
self.pageViewController.datasource = self

let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) as ContentViewController
let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,30,self.view.frame.width,self.view.frame.height-60)

self.addChildViewController(pageViewController as! UIViewController)
self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: How can I fix that then?

Comment: Would you show it to me as a code please? Thank you very much! I appreciate that

Comment: check out this example: https://github.com/olxios/Simple-UIPageViewController-Example

Comment: If you don't see the picture : CGRectMake Is in Red

Comment: And the whole line : self.pageViewController.datasource = self